# Preserve column order of GeoPandas file read

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I have a shapefile I'm reading in using GeoPandas and then I do some geometry conversion of the data but in the process it unfortunately sorts the columns alphabetically.  I need to preserve original order of the columns which has over 200 columns.

Here is the start of the code I'm using.  I imagine I have to somehow store the original column order and apply it to the GeoPandas dataframe.

```
import geopandas as gpd


shpfile = r"C:\data\myfile.shp"
poly = gpd.read_file(shpfile)
poly.head()
```

Comment: Which version of GeoPandas and Fiona  you use  ?

Comment: I have the most recent versions of both installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a variable that stores the index at the end of those 4 lines for later use and then uses that to sort the dataframe down the line, then how about:

```
poly['stored_index'] = poly.index
...
poly.sort_values('stored_index', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  I've tried your suggestion here but it doesn't seem to help I believe since the geopandas read seems to change the order of the columns so I need to get the order before that I believe.  So tried creating a dataframe from a dbf file and user our same code but I keep getting Type Error on the sort_values function.  Any other help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

store the column order right after read-in...

```
import geopandas as gpd

shpfile = r"C:\data\myfile.shp"
poly = gpd.read_file(shpfile)
cols = poly.columns
# ...do something that will change the order of the poly GDF...
# ...then, as long as your work hasn't created any new columns...
poly = poly[cols]
```

if you add new columns do..

```
cols = poly.columns.tolist()
```

and then manipulate the new column/s into that list where you want them in the GDF.

Answer (score 0):

What version of `geopandas` are you using? I found that when I read in a shapefile with `v0.6.1`, the column order was somewhat alphabetized without any command from my script to do so. When I ran the exact same code with the same version of `pandas` (`v1.3.5`) and `geopandas` upgraded to `v0.13.2`, the resulting dataset (in GeoJSON format) had the original column order from the input .shp preserved. I'm not sure what changed between these versions or when it changed (maybe [`v0.11`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/changelog.html#:%7E:text=Fix%20GeoDataFrame.iterfeatures()%20not%20returning%20features%20with%20the%20same%20field%20order%20as%20GeoDataFrame.columns%20(%232396).)?), but I'd recommend setting specific requirements for more recent versions of `geopandas` to fix this.